# Which way would be best to build a coin sorter that can sort by diameter and thickness?

Tags: dc-motor, switches

So lately i've been wanting to build a coin sorter using a raspberry pi or similar that can sort diameter and thicknesses ranging from 5 mm to 35 mm and 0.8 to 3 mm respectively and place the thickest coins at the bottom and the thinnest coins at the top of a designated tube.
Ideally I would love to make it to where I can use a stepper motor, linear screws, and limit switches to properly get a accurate reading +- 0.03 mm and display it on a screen.

So far I've come up with 2 ideas to do this:
1: Have the coin roll through a IR sensor to determine diameter and into the diameter sorter which I will rig so only one slot goes at once straight into the calpier. Which is really just a set up in which the stepper motor pushes a plate and therefore the coin to a limit switch and upon hitting the switch will log the thickness before sending it to its' respective tube.

2. Make both stages use stepper motors to determine diameter and thicknesses at both stages like part 2 for Idea 1.
   However, how exactly I will move the coins without scratching them too much and sort by thickness is beyond me but hey! That's a problem for a later day eh?

Any more ideas or tips would help as well.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: you could probably build a prototype from Lego

Answer (score 1):

The commercial coin verifiers don't work this way; they use non-contact measurements, for example the coin rolls past some coils that are AC energised, and the presence of the coin alters the coil inductance, which can be measured. Also, if the coin is rolling down a ramp, measuring its acceleration gives you an idea of the mass or moment of inertia.

If you want to use direct size measurement, a camera with a close-up lens, and some tightly-controlled light beams could probably be used with an image-recognition system (OpenCV) to give you an accurate measurement.

Non-contact methods like these promise to be faster and more flexible than direct contact with the coin.

Comment: Unfortunately most commercial coin verifiers only accept 3 to 5 types of coins but I have thousands of types ranging from 7 mm all the way up to 35 mm and thicknesses from 0.8 mm to 2.85 mm.